# Does updating dependencies break backwards compatibility (semver major version change)?

Tags: php, semantic-versioning

Let's say I publish a new library `Foo v1.0.0` which requires php 5.6 as a dependency.

Now I would like to use some of the newer language constructs in php 7.0 internally within some of the method implementations. However, my entire public API (method names, parameters, returns, etc.) remain unchanged.

Following [semver](http://semver.org), what version number should I now release?

It seems to me that requiring a new major platform dependency will break backwards compatibility for existing users running php 5.6 who will not be able to simply upgrade with `composer update` so it should now be `v2.0.0`. On the other hand, because nothing has changed about my exposed API, I feel like this should instead just be a patch `v1.0.1`

Comment: Mind explaning why so many questions you asked are having no accepted answers?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski out of today's 60 questions, 8 questions have no answers to accept, and 7 have unacceptable answers to each I have provided feedback in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you got wrong what `backward compatibility` means. If your library's API remains unchanged then it may be just new major version but it is still backward compatible, which means upgrading does not require changes in code using your library. Requiring PHP 7 is just requirement but it got nothing with compatibility.

Other projects I saw usually do major number bump but that's mostly because they only changed requirements but also did some changes to benefit from i.e. new PHP functionalities. So ask yourself if you will really benefit from just requiring PHP 7 or it will be sort of cosmetic change or code cleanup. It also depends how many users your change would really affect.

**EDIT**

Requiring PHP 7 is sometimes huge change as many people are still on 5.x and don't want or can't  upgrade yet and while it is not the backward compatibility issue here, I'd make it `2.0.0` to clearly indicate this change as major.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I find your answer more confusing than clarifying. I'm really unclear as to whether you're implying your answer is version 2.0.0 or 1.0.1. You say No, but it still may be a major version change. I hope I clearly explained my situation with regards to the *"benefit from just requiring PHP 7 or it will be sort of cosmetic change or code cleanup"* I'm really sorry about the delay in providing feedback. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: What would be the **real** benefit for `use some of the newer language constructs in php 7.0 internally within some of the method implementations`? Also, how many people use you library?

Comment: The real benefits are abstracted behind the API, refactoring, code readability, etc. I don't know how many people use the API, but that really doesn't have anything to do with semver.

Comment: I'd say that upgrading a dependency to another major version requires a major upgrade. The simple reason for that is that the dependency (PHP here) can be both indirect via `Foo` but also occur directly. Upgrading `Foo` thus requires me to make changes to my other code to make it compatible to the newer PHP version. I'm currently (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158317/using-different-code-depending-on-the-version-of-another-dependency) trying to find a different solution to that issue when I stumbled across this related question here.