# Using different code depending on the version of another dependency

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

Following situation:

- Library X (maintained by me) depends on library Y version ^2.0.
- For library Y, a newer major version 3 exists that is generally better.
- Upgrading code built on top of Y 2 to Y 3 is straightforward, but requires a few adjustments to the existing code nonetheless.
- Y is a dependency of X, so upgrading it would force users of X to upgrade, too, and thus also requires updating code that uses Y outside of X.

I'd like to make X installable with both Y 2 and Y 3. My approach would be to provide different versions of the code using Y and switch between the versions depending on the installed version, similar to C conditional compilation.

Questions:

- Is there a better approach to this?
- How would I implement conditional code like that?
- Any other comments or suggestions?

Comment: You are about to invent `interface` I think. Unfortunately you cannot compose with PHP really, so perhaps having mid-layer seems to be the simplest approach

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, @MarcinOrlowski, what do you mean with "invent `interface`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If X uses composer, then you may find versions of installed packages using composer's runtime API: https://getcomposer.org/doc/07-runtime.md#installed-versions

Comment: I'm sitting here grinning. :) I literally don't remember what the problem was that I was trying to fix, it's that long ago. It might have been Guzzle in version 5/6/7, not sure. In any case, Composer was still at v1 at that time, so there was no way to use this solution, but it is by today's standards the right way. Thanks!